# some Functor type in Dart

Tags: dart, functional-programming, functor

In Haskell, some Functor fmap

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

In TypeScript,

```
type F<A> = A[];
const F = // type constructor
  <A>(a: A): F<A> => [a];

type map = <A, B> // function => function
  (f: (a: A) => B) =>
  (Fa: F<A>) => F<B>;
```

Similarly, in Dart, I try to implement

```
typedef F<A> = Map<String, A>;
 
typedef Fmap<A, B> = (F<B> Function(F<A>)) (Function(B Function(A)));
```

but the second line has errors, what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I have not the slightest idea what you are trying to do, since I don't get any of the two examples, but this compiles fine:

```
typedef F<A> = Map<String, A>;

typedef Fmap<A, B> = F<B> Function(F<A>) Function(B Function(A));
```

Comment: Thank you nvoigt! Do you know why the extra `( )` does not work? in any chance.

Comment: I guess for the same reason `(int) x = 5; ` does not work, but `int x = 5;` does... the syntax was not made for that.